# Sum, Match and Index Across Multiple Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've spent the last hour unable to get through a relatively straight forward problem.  I would like to sum a range of cells, however it cannot be a fixed formula as the rows and cells will change regularly.

I have tried combining INDEX, MATCH and SUMIF but have not been able to get anywhere.  I've built a sample spreadsheet for what I'm trying to solve for, the image is attached below.

Ideally, I need to sum the values in C assuming that it matches with F2.

Help would greatly be appreciated.

[image: Sample Spreadsheet]

Comment: In E2 you have `Employee B` but in the criteria you have just the `B` is this the way it is in the actual data or do they match?

Comment: Sorry, they match.

Comment: How about using PivotTable?

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS is the way to accomplish your goal - its SUMIF with multiple criteria.

Just make sure that your sum range and criteria ranges all cover the same rows, in this[image: example worksheet] all the range rows are 4-12.

Please note that I changed Employee A to just A to make the criteria match the range.

If you put this formula in F3 it would do what your looking for =SUMIFS(C3:C11,A3:A11,F2,B3:B11,E3)

C3:C11 is the sum range, the other ranges are criteria ranges followed by their criteria respectively.

Comment: Please put the actual formula in text so the OP can copy paste, not in the photo.

Comment: Also with SUMIFS you do not need to limit the reference ranges: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,F$2,B:B,$E2)`